# matplotlib - symbol to use for a vessel

Tags: python, matplotlib, symbols

I don't know the name for it (does anyone know what it's called?) but i'm curious if matplotlib has a symbol such as this? [image] (https://www.marinetraffic.com/img/shipicons/blue1_85.png)

For reference, this is taken from https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/home/centerx:-12.0/centery:24.9/zoom:4

I believe this is the current list of symbols https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html

Edit: Here the marker created by the code below. Thanks @ted930511

Edit 2: Slightly updated version of using `vertices = [(0, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (4, 0), (1, -1), (-1, -1), (0, 0)]`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Path` to create custom marker. Details see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/path_api.html)

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
vertices = [(0, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (1, -1), (-1, -1), (0, 0)]
p = Path(vertices,[1,2,2,2,2,2,79])

x = range(10)
y = x

plt.scatter(x, y, marker=p, s=300)
```

[image]

Comment: And the example: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/marker_path.html

Comment: @te930511 how would I make it longer? Trying to define the vertices in your code like this but I think i'm off
(middle left), (top left), (top right), (middle right), (botton right), (bottom left), (middle left).
think I got it now